# How to copy fonts folder from node_module using Brunch

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch

I am following this blog post but the fonts are not getting copied.

http://cloudless.studio/articles/4-installing-font-awesome-from-npm-in-phoenix

#### Description

What's the essence of the issue?
Fonts folder is not included

#### Expected behavior

I expect the fonts folder to be included

#### Environment

1. Brunch: 2.8.2
2. Node: v6.3.1
3. NPM: 3.10.3
4. Operating system: OS X 10.11.6

#### `package.json` contents

```
{
  "repository": {},
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "brunch build --production",
    "watch": "brunch watch --stdin"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "google-maps": "^3.2.1",
    "phoenix": "file:deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:deps/phoenix_html",
    "sass-brunch": "^2.6.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-brunch": "~6.0.0",
    "brunch": "~2.8.0",
    "clean-css-brunch": "~2.0.0",
    "css-brunch": "~2.0.0",
    "javascript-brunch": "~2.0.0",
    "uglify-js-brunch": "~2.0.1"
  }
}
```

#### brunch config contents

```
exports.config = {
  // See http://brunch.io/#documentation for docs.
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"

      // To use a separate vendor.js bundle, specify two files path
      // http://brunch.io/docs/config#-files-
      // joinTo: {
      //  "js/app.js": /^(web\/static\/js)/,
      //  "js/vendor.js": /^(web\/static\/vendor)|(deps)/
      // }
      //
      // To change the order of concatenation of files, explicitly mention here
      // order: {
      //   before: [
      //     "web/static/vendor/js/jquery-2.1.1.js",
      //     "web/static/vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      //   ]
      // }
    },
    stylesheets: {
      joinTo: "css/app.css",
      order: {
        after: ["web/static/css/app.css"] // concat app.css last
      }
    },
    templates: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"
    }
  },

  conventions: {
    // This option sets where we should place non-css and non-js assets in.
    // By default, we set this to "/web/static/assets". Files in this directory
    // will be copied to `paths.public`, which is "priv/static" by default.
    assets: [
      /^(web\/static\/assets)/,
            /^(node_modules\/font-awesome)/
    ]
  },

  // Phoenix paths configuration
  paths: {
    // Dependencies and current project directories to watch
    watched: [
      "web/static",
      "test/static",
        'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts',
    ],

    // Where to compile files to
    public: "priv/static"
  },

  // Configure your plugins
  plugins: {
    babel: {
      // Do not use ES6 compiler in vendor code
      ignore: [/web\/static\/vendor/]
    }
  },

  modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      "js/app.js": ["web/static/js/app"]
    }
  },

  npm: {
    enabled: true
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Omin's answer is pretty terse so I'll try give more details.

As of recent versions of brunch, non JavaScript or CSS assets that are available via `node_modules` will not be included by Brunch.

The guide [here](http://brunch.io/docs/using-modules#including-modules-styles) points out that the only way to include assets that are not JavaScript or CSS assets is to copy them manually. It recommends doing that via `postinstall` hook in npm.

So how might that look in your phoenix application? Quite simple..

in your package.json:

`"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "cp -R node_modules/font-awesome/fonts web/static/assets/fonts"
}`

Ultimately I don't think this solution is great, but it does get the job done. In the article you listed the author links to a set of [great alternatives](http://cloudless.studio/articles/21-front-end-packages-with-phoenix-and-brunch) because they realised their approach no longer works as of Brunch 2.8.2.

Of the alternatives using webpack seems like one of the best alternatives. Phoenix can work just fine with webpack, and they even provide a short guide on [how to do just that.](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/static-assets#section-using-another-asset-management-system-in-phoenix)

Comment: yeah... I was really disappointed (a little pissed off) when I found out. I ended up using `postinstall` as well: https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-copy-fonts-folder-from-node-module-using-brunch/1733/9. Anyhow, thanks for taking your time to thoroughly answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

I used the [copycat-brunch](https://github.com/cmelgarejo/copycat-brunch) plugin to do that, it's pretty simple. In the brunch-config.js file I did:

```
plugins: {
    copycat: {
      fonts: [
        "node_modules/font-awesome/fonts",
        "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts"
      ]
    }
}
```

and the fonts were properly copied to priv/static/fonts. It also works for images.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't categorize node_modules as 'assets' even if they match the
>   regexp

https://github.com/brunch/brunch/blob/41f0c1f298bf94024621457c66caee74ea6d4ddc/CHANGELOG.md#brunch-26-apr-2-2016